# Is it possible to recover a VisualForce Page that was overwritten?

Tags: visualforce

I am not sure why, but when I tried to create a new VF page, it redirected me back to my custom landing page and then I proceeded to overwrite it.

I have a manual backup I took of it about a month ago, but it doesn't reflect the most recent functionality.

Is there any way for me to retrieve it? I was under the impression that SalesForce had some kind of version control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been burned by that...

1. is it a production environment? if so, SF should be able to help you.
2. Did you develop this in eclipse? if so, you may have a local history.

install subversion for your company. if your company doesn't have it, it's a poor practice, and they should. Also, it's an opportunity for you to shine.
https://www.google.com/search?q=salesforce+subversion+eclipse&oq=subversion+sales&aqs=chrome.3.57j0l3.5019j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: 1) No ; 2) No ; should I start recoding ?

Comment: Call SF as a just in case, but yea, it doesn't look good for you.. If you deploy code by eclipse, you can do a code backup,  but it sounds like your code was done by the web... sorry bro